# Find rows where any column matches a search pattern

Tags: oracle

I have a table `"Test"` with 15 different columns of different data types.

I'm looking for rows having characters like `"ABC"`. But `"ABC"` can be present in any column and I want to find whole records having `"ABC"`.

I cannot restrict the row using a WHERE clause, because I really do not have any idea in which column the `ABC` resides? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS? You've tagged both SQL Server and Oracle

Comment: Sorry i just tag both . But the question is for ORACLE.

Comment: Lots of `OR`s, I guess!

Comment: yes that is a  solution.  here in example i had given only 15 column but in my scenario it is near about 50 columns . so if there is any alternative let me suggest. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is the plain and simple "brute force" way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "Test"
WHERE (col1 LIKE '%ABC%' OR
       col2 LIKE '%ABC%' OR
       col3 LIKE '%ABC%' OR
       ...
       col15 LIKE '%ABC%');
```

Parentheses won't be necessary if you don't have additional `WHERE` expressions. 
Probably faster (and more robust in any case) than concatenating all columns for a single `LIKE` test.

Comment: In *PostgreSQL*, you could just `SELECT * FROM tbl t WHERE t::text LIKE '%ABC%`. [Details in this answer on code review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/sql-search-for-a-keyword-in-several-columns-of-a-table/7231#7231) I don't think you can cast an entire row or record to `varchar` in Oracle, or at least I would not know about it.

Comment: Yes the query you suggest will be perfactly work but i just wanted to minimize the query.Nice i refer your answer on Code review. actully i m finiding something like that only "SELECT * FROM tbl t WHERE t::text LIKE '%ABC%" will work on it how can i find some similar solution in oracle.

Comment: Minimise the query definition or minimise the work done when it is run?  Because these are different aims.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 11g, you can use [UNPIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

```
select *
from test unpivot (any_column for source_column in (col1, col2, col3, ...))
where any_column like '%ABC%';
```

Note that if a row contains ABC in more than one columns, this query returns all of them. If you need the original rows, use a subquery

```
select *
from test
where id in (
  select id
  from test unpivot (any_column for source_column in (col1, col2, col3, ...))
  where any_column like '%ABC%'
);
```

Comment: it looks fine let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Using the instr built-in function you can do like this:

```
Select * from Test where instr(col1||col2||col3,'ABC') <> 0;
```

Comment: Such query will return row where col1='A' and col2='BC'.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you have to add a separator between each column.

Comment: @NicolasDurand: And be certain that the separator cannot be part of the search pattern ...

Comment: @Nicolas 
Instr function is use to find the occurrence of particular character from a given string based on given specification.
eg."SELECT INSTR('CORPORATE FLOOR','OR',3,2) "Instring" FROM DUAL;" output---> 14.. So how can we use Column in Instr function?

Comment: The instr function is taking a string as the 1st parameter, so column are accepted, Oracle will cast the column to a string if the column type is not: [http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php]